# Streaming Music Over UDP Python

Tags: python, tcp, udp, mp3

I am trying to create a program that streams Music (MP3 files) over a UDP connection. So far I have created a program that sends the entire MP3 file over and writes it to a file on the client's machine. The client then plays the file with `pygame.mixer`.

This obviously is not streaming. I can not for the life of me figure out how to stream the music over a to the client.

If someone could point me on the right direction that would be great.

Comment: I am just curious is all, I feel it could be an interesting project.

Comment: read this: http://www.jejik.com/articles/2007/01/streaming_audio_over_tcp_with_python-gstreamer/

Comment: You could break the MP3 file into its individual frames, number them, and send them over. If a frame goes missing, perhaps you could assume it's all zeros or something.

Comment: I figured it out using WAV files and PyAudio

Comment: could you share with us what you figured out? e.g. post some code?

Answer (score 0):

Live Streaming with udp would mean something like rtsp streaming. Take a look at live555 if you want to do some of that.  There is a server available within it [live555mediaServer or some name like that] which you can use for rtsp streaming.

Gstreamer can also allow you to do basic stream using just pure rtp. Something like the following pipelines can allow you to do it.

```
 gst-launch filesrc location=<yourfile> ! mp3parse ! rtpmpapay <someoptions> ! udpsink port=<someport>
```

and you could recieve it and dejitter it and then depay it and then decode and play it

```
 gst-launch udpsrc port<the-some-port in the sender> ! gstrtpjitterbuffer ! rtpmpapay ! decodebin2 ! queue ! autoaudiosink
```

Or you could use ffserver to do the streaming. A bit of googling to understand rtp/rtsp would help you understand this stuff. There are plenty of servers already available to send the data out. [Darwin, Live555]

There are other forms of streaming too [rtmp which will need flv files] and smooth streaming and HLS. RTSP is what is the true live streaming protocol.